# conflicting types for read_cfg()

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, shared-libraries

I have 2 .c file  ,  in one of the files i will try to call the read_cfg(struct) to assign the data in the structure but i am getting error of "conflicting types " in the .h file

example.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"example.h"

struct config /structure
{
char data[10];
};

int main()
{
int n=0;
struct data d;
read_cfg(&d);   //function call
}
```

example.h

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H
extern void read_cfg(struct); //ERROR
```

examplelib.c

```
struct config  //structure
{
    char data[10];
};


void read_cfg(struct config_data *cfg) //function implementation 
{
struct config_data tmp;
strcpy(tmp.data,"helo");
cfg=&tmp;
}
```

Any help will be useful for me

Thanks

Comment: Please review the code in your question: you have 3 different structure types: `struct config`, `struct data` and `struct config_data`. Are these supposed to be the same type? Please read on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> extern void read_cfg(struct); //ERROR

The error was because you have mis-matched argument type. It should be `void read_cfg(struct config_data *)` instead.

Btw, you don't need `extern` keyword for functions - by default functions have external linkage (except for static functions).

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for `read_cfg()` function (in `example.h`) and your definition of `read_cfg()` (in `examplelib.c`) don't match.
Change the declaration in `example.h` to:

```
extern void read_cfg(struct config_data *cfg);
```